# How to set page margin and templates in a word document?

Tags: macos, ms-word, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I want to change the page margin in a word document using word javascript API for a word add-in to be used in Mac. There is no functions available to directly set the page margin. Is there any alternative way to do this? Also, How to apply a template programmatically?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, so I'll make it a comment and if it works, I'll make it an answer: Use the body.getOoxml method to get the ooxml, there is a <w:sectPr> element near the end that defines the margins. Edit this string to replace the defaults with your values. Then use the insertOoxml method with "Replace" as the location to replace the original ooxml with your edited ooxml.

Comment: This is what i thought of too. But I have some other formatting that I have to apply and if the user already has a lot of  text in the body (like a 1000 page document), it seems impossible to change the formatting and apply styles by this approach. Won't it be slow and hard to develop? For every change, I have to get the Ooxml content, modify it and insert it back into the document. Is there any way to simplify this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported in the API today. Please add a request to consider it in the future
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/163566-add-in-word

Comment: After 5 years, do we still have any way of setting page size or margins in Office.js?